# WAMP Issue With PHP

Tags: php, html, wampserver

Please excuse my terrible formatting, I am teaching myself html, css, and php.

I have a folder on my WAMP www folder, with html, css, and php. I am trying to get the information inputed in the form to get sent to an email address. My html with css shows up fine on the localhost,however when I click the submit button the url on the localhost changes to the php file, but I get a "localhost refused to connect." Besides, well, everything, what am I doing wrong here?

This is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/text.css">

    

    <body background="image/wallpaperbetter.jpg">

        <p> //code

        </p>

    </body>

    <div>
        <form method = "post" name = "myemailform" action = "https://localhost/xxxx/form-to-email.php">

            <label for="name">Name(optional):</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <label for="Home">Home:</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <label for="City">City:</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <label for="State">State:</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <label for="Zip Code">Zip Code:</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <label for="Country">Country:</label>
            <input type = "text"><br>

            <input type = "submit" value = "submit">


        </form>
    </div>
    

</html>
```

This is the php file

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

//Collect input
$name = $_POST['name'];
$home = $_POST['Home'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$state = $_POST['State'];
$zip_code = $_POST['Zip Code'];
$country = $_POST['Country'];

//Validate
if(empty($home)||empty($city)||empty($state)||empty($zip_code)||empty(country))
{
    echo "Please enter all fields. (Name is Optional)";
}



$email_from = 'xxxx';
$email_subject = "New Submission";
$email_body = "New submission\nName:$name\nHome:$home\nCity:$city\nState:$state\nZip Code:$zip_code\nCountry:country"
$to =  "xxxx";
$headers = "xxxx";

//Send the email
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body);

?>
```

Comment: does not this: `action = "https://localhost/xxxx/form-to-email.php"` mean that it is _supposed_ to go to your PHP file?

Comment: also, I believe each "input" tag requires the "name" attribute, not just the "label" tag. E.g.: `<input name="city" type="text">` But I could be wrong, there are a lot of nuances in HTML

Comment: "Refuses to connect" confirm that you actually do have "form-to-email.php" in the "xxxx" main folder of your Document Root. Also confirm there are no syntax errors in that PHP code. Try running it from the command line. You may need to comment out the $_POST lines as those will **only** be effective from the web server.

Comment: What is the URL of the HTML file containing the form?

Comment: @UncaAlby Yes, it is supposed to, but the server is unable to connect to it.
Also, my whole project, the project folder with html css and php is in the WAMP directory folder.

Comment: @DavidHernandez if your entire project is on the same level as the entire project, then what is "xxxx"? That generally indicates the file is in a sub-folder by that name. Try manually putting "https://localhost/xxxx/form-to-email.php" on the address bar of your browser. If it can find in a readable folder "xxxx" then it should at least connect and attempt to run that script.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML when you use **label for** you have to give your input exactly the same id as you used in the label.

You can also let the browser do the *empty* checking by putting the **required** attribute in each of your required input fields.

```
<div>
    <form method = "post" name = "myemailform" action = "https://localhost/xxxx/form-to-email.php">

    <label for="name">Name (optional):</label>
    <input id="name" type = "text"><br>

    <label for="Home">Home:</label>
    <input id="Home" type = "text" required><br>

    <label for="City">City:</label>
    <input id="City" type = "text" required><br>

    <label for="State">State:</label>
    <input id="State" type = "text" required><br>

    <label for="Zip Code">Zip Code:</label>
    <input id="Zip Code" type = "text" required><br>

    <label for="Country">Country:</label>
    <input id="Country" type = "text" required><br>

    <input type = "submit" value = "submit">

</form>
</div>
```

In your PHP you need to concatenate your variables outside of your strings. You need to close the string, concatenate the variable name, concatenate the new string and close it, concatenate the variable name and so forth. I've put in on multiple lines to make it easier to read:

```
$email_from = 'xxxx';
$email_subject = "New Submission";
    $email_body =   "New submission\nName:" . $name . 
                    "\nHome:" . $home . 
                    "\nCity:" . $city .
                    "\nState:" . $state .
                    "\nZip Code:" . $zip_code .
                    "\nCountry:" . $country";
$to =  "xxxx";
$headers = "xxxx";
```

In the future you'll also look in to santizing your strings when you read them from a form to protect your site/server.

Comment: *"In the future you'll also look in to santizing your strings when you read them from a form to protect your site/server."* This is very true, but might I suggest that be done **immediately** in order to get into the habit.